# Xamarin.Forms PCL & ServiceStack 4.5

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, servicestack

I have a Xamarin.Forms PCL project, profile 7. I'm trying to troubleshoot some errors coming up when I try to create a new instance of JsonServiceClient:

*System.ArgumentException: PclExport.Instance needs to be initialized*

*System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase' threw an exception.*

Searching for my errors, I discovered:

```
IosPclExportClient.Configure()
```

and

```
AndroidPclExportClient.Configure()
```

However, I am not sure if that applies here since the Forms PCL project abstracts away the specifics of iOS/Android/etc.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

The PCL abstracts it, that's correct. But you need to call the `IosPclExportClient.Configure()` in your `AppDelegate` or `Application.Main()` and `AndroidPclExportClient.Configure()` in your `MainActivity`, because they are initializing some platform specific objects, that can be used in you shared code  afterwards.